# Поменять местами столбцы в массиве

Tags: c#

Нужно поменять местами столбцы k1 и k2
у меня чет не получается меняется только один столбец и все ((
-Задания такое 
Данные два числа k1 и k2 и матрица размера 4 x 10. Поменять местами столбцы матрицы с номерами k1 и k2 
от все есть только не получается поменять k1 и k2  местами

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StudentSimpleProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите количество строк m:\t");
            int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Введите количество столбцов n:\t");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int i, j;
            Random rand = new Random();
            int[,] mass = new int[m, n];
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    mass[i, j] = rand.Next(-10, 30);
                    Console.Write(mass[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
            Console.Write("Введите номер столбца k1:\t");
            int k1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;
            Console.Write("Введите номер столбца k2:\t");
            int k2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
               mass[i, k2] = mass[i, k1];

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Новый массив:");
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(mass[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mass[i, k2] = mass[i, k1]; - копирование, а не перемена местами.

Comment: а как записать код , чтобы столбцы поменялись местами ?

Comment: А вы подумайте, как его написать надо.

Comment: Ладно вам томить новичка, ведь он же не понимает. Намёк: чтобы поменять местами две переменные нужно использовать третью. Дальше сообразите?

Comment: Я уже смотрел много примеров как менять столбцы и строки , пробовал что то свое слепить но  ничего не получалось !

Comment: @РадуйсяЖизни на столе две монеты. Задача - поменять их местами, при условии что держать в руках более одной монеты в любой момент времени нельзя. Это если бытовые аналогии проводить.

Comment: Задания сделал ) понадобилось около часу чтобы понять как делать его .